# why the mysql has two root user

Tags: mysql

Today when I check MySQL 5.7 using this command:

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

but the output has 2 root user:

```
root    *6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9   mysql_native_password   localhost
mysql.session   *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE   mysql_native_password   localhost
mysql.sys   *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE   mysql_native_password   localhost
root    *65EFA6253C9C6975BF9BB0EBD77170A04B321D39   mysql_native_password   %
exporter    *F2FBAC0B35510E7398C37EF11A7021EB76FB9D39   mysql_native_password   localhost
```

why has 2 root user? what may cause this situation? is it normal? could I deleted the first root user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root@%` would allow access from all locations (IP-s).

`root@localhost` would only allow access from localhost.

They are two different users maybe ,with two different passwords and different accesses.

Check the manual for more information:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-access.html

Comment: Also `mysql` CLI tool will work through the file socket in case of `root@localhost` that has a lower overhead than network connection.

Comment: Phrased differently, `localhost` is not included in the wildcard `%`.